# Does npm run <script> adds any environment property?

Tags: webpack, package.json

I have a `package.json` file in which I have "build" key under scripts object, which triggers my webpack.

But instead of using `npm` run build , If I just run the webpack, I get an error `webpack is not recognised as internal or external command`. Does this mean that `npm run <script>` , sets some env variable before running webpack?

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.28.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run something from a npm script it looks for binaries inside `node_modules/.bin`. That is why when you tried to run just webpack it failed, you didn't specified where it was and your system didn't know where to look at.

Answer (score 2):

Given the `scripts` section in your `package.json`, it does not set any ENV variables. However it is possible to do that if you'd like to. For instance, to set ENV variables conveniently on all
operating systems, you could use a package such as [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) (`npm i --save-dev cross-env`) and update your `scripts` section to something similar to

`{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config config/webpack.config.js"
  }
}`

and access them in your config file (`webpack.config.js`) as `process.env.NODE_ENV`

In addition to that, you could make running `webpack` instead of `npm run build` succeed by installing webpack packages globally (`npm i -g webpack webpack-cli`), but this is **not recommended**.
It's good practice to have packages necessary installed locally and to depend on the package versions defined in `package.json`. Even doing so doesn't necessarily set
ENV variables, you need to do that explicitly as stated above or by using your preferred approach.

In essence, your `npm` which is installed globally, takes care of `npm run build` which in return triggers `webpack` command which is linked to your local packages. Trying to run `webpack` directly in your case fails as webpack packages are not installed globally.